# не печатается результат

Tags: python

Есть задание
Создать 2 класса `truck` и `car`, которые являются наследниками класса `auto`
**Класс `truck` имеет:**

- Дополнительный обязательный атрибут `max_load`.
- Переопределённый метод `move`, перед появлением надписи `«move»` выводит надпись `«attention»`, его реализацию сделать при помощи оператора `super`.
- А так же дополнительный метод `load`. При его вызове происходит пауза 1 сек., затем выдаётся сообщение `«load»` и снова пауза 1 сек.

**Класс `car` имеет**

- дополнительный обязательный атрибут `max_speed` и при вызове метода `move`, после появления надписи `«move»` должна появиться надпись `«max speed is <max_speed>»`.
  Вместо `<max_speed>` должно выводится значение обязательного атрибута `max_speed`.

Создать по 2 объекта для каждого из классов `truck` и `car`, проверить все их методы и атрибуты.

```
class auto:
    brand = 'audi'
    age = 5
    color = 'red'
    mark = 'a8'
    weight = 5000

    def __init__(self, brand, age, mark):
        self.brand = brand
        self.age = age
        self.mark = mark

    def move(self):
        print(self.brand, self.mark, 'move')

    def birthday(self):
        self.age +=1
        print(self.age)

    def stop(self):
        print(self.brand, self.mark, 'stop')

class truck(auto):
    max_load = 3000
    def __init__(self, max_load = 2000):
        self.max_load = max_load
        super().__init__('attention', self.move(), self.stop())




a = truck
a.truck(auto)
```

Comment: Поправьте отступы

Comment: поправил ничего не поменялось...

Comment: Я просил поправить отступы ЗДЕСЬ, а не у вас.

Comment: Много что не так. Чтобы метод что-то сделал, нужно его вызвать.

Comment: Научитесь лучше сразу классы называть с большой буквы. Очень режет глаз.

Comment: ок , что мне нужно сделать подскажите , я эту тему с классами не понял до конца. Про большие буквы записал на заметку, меня интересует именно класс Truck , как его правильно реализовать? все что выше то работает вроде как . Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общих чертах как-то так. Метод `load()` сделайте сами

```
class Auto:
    def __init__(self, brand, age, mark):
        self.brand = brand
        self.age = age
        self.mark = mark

    def move(self):
        print(self.brand, self.mark, 'move')


class Truck(Auto):
    def __init__(self, brand, age, mark, max_load=2000):
        super().__init__(brand, age, mark)
        self.max_load = max_load

    def move(self):
        print('attention')
        super().move()


class Car(Auto):
    def __init__(self, brand, age, mark, max_speed=300):
        super().__init__(brand, age, mark)
        self.max_speed = max_speed

    def move(self):
        super().move()
        print(f'max speed is{self.max_speed}')


truck = Truck('SCANIA', 10, '"s 770"')
truck.move()

car = Car('VW', 3, 'Touran', 320)
car.move()
```

Comment: Не понял , почему метод move для дочерных классов повторяем? Ведь он берется с родителя разве нет?

Comment: @Mr.OIITiMiCT см. задание - "Переопределённый метод move". Он переопределяется в потомке

Comment: Спасибо , буду разбираться дальше